# Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, annotations, components

I have the following code running on my local server.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <script src="https://jspm.io/system@0.16.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.19/angular2.dev.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <my-app></my-app>
  <script>
     System.config({
       paths: {
          '*': '*.js',
          'angular2/*': 'angular2/*'
      }
 });
 System.import('main');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above is the index.html page.

```
import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app'
})
@View({
  template: '<h1>My first Angular 2 App</h1>'
})
class AppComponent {
}

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

The above is the main.js file.

When I run this on the server I get the following in console.

```
http://localhost:63342/es6/main.js:3:1: Unexpected token @
angular2.dev.js:752 TypeError: Error loading "main" at      http://localhost:63342/es6/main.js
Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
angular2.dev.js:753 TypeError: Error loading "main" at http://localhost:63342/es6/main.js
Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
  at Zone.longStackTraceZone.getLongStacktrace (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.19/angular2.dev.js:728:35)
  at Zone.longStackTraceZone.onError (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.19/angular2.dev.js:753:19)
  at Zone.run (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.19/angular2.dev.js:92:14)
  at zoneBoundFn (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.19/angular2.dev.js:66:19)
  at D (https://jspm.io/es6-module-loader@0.16.5.js:1:7439)
  at I (https://jspm.io/es6-module-loader@0.16.5.js:1:7071)
  at O.7.O.when (https://jspm.io/es6-module-loader@0.16.5.js:1:10745)
  at w.7.w.run (https://jspm.io/es6-module-loader@0.16.5.js:1:9781)
  at e.3.e._drain (https://jspm.io/es6-module-loader@0.16.5.js:1:1740)
  at 3.e.drain (https://jspm.io/es6-module-loader@0.16.5.js:1:1394)
--- Sun Apr 26 2015 08:27:39 GMT+0530 (IST) - 738ms ago
 Error
  at Function.getStacktraceWithUncaughtError (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.19/angular2.dev.js:699:32)
  at Zone.longStackTraceZone.fork (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.19/angular2.dev.js:758:43)
  at Zone.bind (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.19/angular2.dev.js:64:21)
  at Function.Zone.bindArguments (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.19/angular2.dev.js:195:22)
  at t.fnNames.forEach.obj.(anonymous function) [as then] (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.19/angular2.dev.js:186:42)
  at k (https://jspm.io/es6-module-loader@0.16.5.js:1:21515)
  at https://jspm.io/es6-module-loader@0.16.5.js:1:22664
  at Zone.run (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-   alpha.19/angular2.dev.js:89:19)
  at zoneBoundFn (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.19/angular2.dev.js:66:19)
  at D (https://jspm.io/es6-module-loader@0.16.5.js:1:7439)
--- Sun Apr 26 2015 08:27:39 GMT+0530 (IST) - 739ms ago
Error
  at Function.getStacktraceWithUncaughtError (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.19/angular2.dev.js:699:32)
  at Zone.longStackTraceZone.fork (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.19/angular2.dev.js:758:43)
  at Zone.bind (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.19/angular2.dev.js:64:21)
  at Function.Zone.bindArguments (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.19/angular2.dev.js:195:22)
  at t.fnNames.forEach.obj.(anonymous function) [as then] (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.19/angular2.dev.js:186:42)
  at x.import (https://jspm.io/es6-module-loader@0.16.5.js:1:22539)
  at x.$__global.upgradeSystemLoader.e.import (https://jspm.io/system@0.16.7.js:5:1180)
  at http://localhost:63342/es6/index.html:17:18
 angular2.dev.js:752 TypeError: Cannot read property '__useDefault' of    undefined
angular2.dev.js:753 TypeError: Cannot read property '__useDefault' of undefined
  at https://jspm.io/system@0.16.7.js:5:1220
  at Zone.run (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.19/angular2.dev.js:89:19)
  at zoneBoundFn (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.19/angular2.dev.js:66:19)
  at D (https://jspm.io/es6-module-loader@0.16.5.js:1:7439)
  at I (https://jspm.io/es6-module-loader@0.16.5.js:1:7071)
  at O.7.O.when (https://jspm.io/es6-module-loader@0.16.5.js:1:10745)
  at w.7.w.run (https://jspm.io/es6-module-loader@0.16.5.js:1:9781)
  at e.3.e._drain (https://jspm.io/es6-module-loader@0.16.5.js:1:1740)
  at 3.e.drain (https://jspm.io/es6-module-loader@0.16.5.js:1:1394)
  at MutationObserver.t (https://jspm.io/es6-module-loader@0.16.5.js:1:3302)
--- Sun Apr 26 2015 08:27:39 GMT+0530 (IST) - 742ms ago
Error
  at Function.getStacktraceWithUncaughtError (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.19/angular2.dev.js:699:32)
  at Zone.longStackTraceZone.fork (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.19/angular2.dev.js:758:43)
  at Zone.bind (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.19/angular2.dev.js:64:21)
  at Function.Zone.bindArguments (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.19/angular2.dev.js:195:22)
  at t.fnNames.forEach.obj.(anonymous function) [as then] (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.19/angular2.dev.js:186:42)
  at x.$__global.upgradeSystemLoader.e.import (https://jspm.io/system@0.16.7.js:5:1195)
  at http://localhost:63342/es6/index.html:17:18
```

The above code is taken from [angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/guide/setup.html), the official angular 2 website. If the same code is executed in [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MRz2i7sjupzxERPAa3SF?p=preview), I get the output "My first Angular 2 App" but not in my local.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems we have to import traceur-runtime.js and set traceur options.

Here is the [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/P17i9CS10Vwqd7vJSesr?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="https://github.jspm.io/jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.87/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
<script src="https://jspm.io/system@0.16.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.19/angular2.dev.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<my-app></my-app>
<script>
System.config({
    traceurOptions: {
        annotations: true,
        memberVariables: true,
        types: true
    },
    paths: {
        '*': '*.js',
        'angular2/*': 'angular2/*'
    }
});
System.import('main');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your file name in which you declared angular app.

It should be the `main.es6.js` instead of `main.js`

The file-name format should always be the name specified in `System.import('main')` which is `main.` + `es6.` + `js`

[**Read this article for better uderstanding**](http://www.htmlxprs.com/post/54/creating-a-super-simple-todo-app-using-angular-2-tutorial)

Comment: I already tried changing the file name. Are you telling I need to change only the file name or also the System.import statement along with it. Changing only the file name from main.js to main.es6.js does not work, the same issue shows up.

Comment: @Kaushik I'm only saying to change file name that should solve your issue

Comment: @Kaushik can you reproduce the problem in plunkr, see the problem I reproduced here http://plnkr.co/edit/Is9U5q3oydB7DY8DKuBE?p=preview, if you rename the file to main.es6.js then it will fix. are you sure you are using `es5`/`es6`?

Comment: @pankajparkar The snippet is already there in plunkr. I have mentioned in the last passage of my question that it works fine in plunkr but not in local server. I have mentioned the links there. Can you try running it from a local server and try the same?

Comment: @pankajparkar I checked the plnkr link that you commented. It works there. :) The same exact code when I run in local server it does not work.

Comment: @pankajparkar check the question. I have posted the images itself